# Confused about entering text into Input element with React Testing Library

Tags: react-testing-library

I've been building React Testing Library (RTL) tests for nearly a year so am confused why I suddenly can't enter text into an input field.

This custom search component must have the HTML structure it does for reasons I won't bother you with:

```
return (
  <div className='input button-container' data-testid='search'>
    <input type='search' data-testid='search-input' className='search' />
    <span data-testid='search-click' onClick={handleSearchClick}></span>
  </div>
);
```

I've removed some superfluous code for clarity.

Here's what I'm doing in my test:

```
const searchInput = queryByTestId('search-input');
fireEvent.change(searchInput, { target: { value: 'abcde' }});
```

This seems correct to me but when I check, the `abcde` value is not being entered into the `input` element.  Any ideas why not?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that queryBy* queries could work for this. I would suggest to test this (getByTestId) :

```
const searchInput = getByTestId('search-input');
fireEvent.change(searchInput, { target: { value: 'abcde' }});
```

This works for sure. Never tested this use case with queryBy* but it might return an array or something not suitable for a fireEvent.

Comment: thanks for trying to help!  The problem turned out to be a typo.  For the `input` element, I had added an event handler called `onInput` when it clearly should have been `onChange`.

Late night coding sometimes isn't advisable.